# Data Not Set in admin Grid in magento2

Tags: magento2, order-collection

[image]

I am Filter the Order Collection. Code give as

```
protected function searchResultToOutput(SearchResultInterface $searchResult)
{
    $arrItems = [];
    $arrItems['items'] = [];
    foreach ($searchResult->getItems() as $item) {
        $itemData = [];
        foreach ($item->getCustomAttributes() as $attribute) {
            $itemData[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getValue();
        }
        $arrItems['items'][] = $itemData;
        $arrItems['totalRecords'] = $searchResult->getTotalCount();
    }

    //$sellerId = "25";
    $currentUser=$this->getCurrentUserId();
    $arr= array_filter($arrItems['items'], function($e) use ($currentUser) {
        return in_array($currentUser, explode(",", $e["current_seller_id"]));
    });
    $arrItems['items']=$arr;
    return $arrItems;
}
```

This code return the filtered array as i mention in snapshot But it not set on Grid.
Actually this collection is filter for the sake of current_seller can see own orders.
Data is not set in grid.
Guid me why not data is set  in Grid Even Collection .

Comment: Did you reindex your site? php bin/magento indexer:reset && php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: wait i am running these commands

Comment: same result.
Just buffer the grid not data set in grid But in XHR i debug array return correctly But not set in grid. have any idea about it ?

Comment: Do you have a module that extends products_listing.xml?

Comment: Also try to remove your ui_bookmark table records for product_listing. This will reset all your filters

Comment: no am sot extends any product_listing.xml etc .
actually i create multi admins . Order Grid data show for some admins and not show for other admin. i don't why order grid set data to login with other admin

Comment: Did you remove the records in the ui_bookmark?

Comment: @CompactCode it resolve .
i replace the "filter_array" code with foreach code then data set in grid.
`$seller_order_arr = [];
        foreach ($arrItems['items'] as  $row) {
            if ($row['current_seller_id'] != null){
                if (in_array($currentUser, explode(",", $row['current_seller_id']))){
                    $seller_order_arr[] = $row;
                }
            }
        }
 $arrItems['items'] = $seller_order_arr;`

Comment: You should not adjust magento core filles though. But i am glad it works

Comment: what do you mean @CompactCode

Comment: Where did you adjust that?